# Make picasso to play well with headers like "if-modified-since" and "ETag"

Tags: android, picasso

In my app image contents are changing frequently (like once in a week) and imageurl remains the same. I am using picasso for image loading. My query is to can I set age to cache-entry and use the headers like 'if-modified-since' and 'ETag'?

Comment: AFAIK, this is handled by the underlying HTTP engine. Add OkHttp to your project, configure it to use a cache, and use that with Picasso.

Comment: @CommonsWare Did you mean adding network interceptors?

Comment: No, I mean [configuring the OkHttp cache directory and rules](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#response-caching).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I resolved it.

```
Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {

        public static final String TAG = "RequestInterceptor";

        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            final Request original = chain.request(); //Original request initiated
            final Response response;    //Response for given url




                    // Request customization: add request headers
                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder().header("if-modified-since", last-modified-date-for-image).method(original.method(), original.body());

                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                    response = chain.proceed(request);


                    Log.d(TAG, "Intercepting status code : " + response.code());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Intercepting requests : Url :" + request.url().toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Intercepting requests : if-modified-since : " + response.header("if-modified-since".toLowerCase()));



            /* if response code is 200 means we have updated image otherwise return older one.*/
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                return response;
            } else {
                return chain.proceed(original);
            }

        }
    };


    //Create OkHttpClient for picasso downloader and add request interceptor.
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    //Instantiate okHttp3Downloader with okHttpClient 
    OkHttp3Downloader okHttpDownloader = new OkHttp3Downloader(okHttpClient);

    //Create picasso instance
    picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this).downloader(okHttpDownloader).build();

    //load image in imageview 'img'
    picasso.load("image url").into(img);
```

You can use 'ETag' instead of 'if-modified-since'.

**Known issue :** images are not getting loaded when device is offline. Please load it from cache forcefully.